# How to call a method on an element within a list that is contained in a Kotlin Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I am wondering if there's a better way to call a method on an element within a list that is contained in a Flow. Currently i'm doing this but i don't like calling map() twice:

```
override fun getEarnings(): Flow<List<Transaction>> {
    return transactionDao.getEarnings().map {
        it.map { transaction -> transaction.asDomainModel() }
    }
}
```

the getEarnings() method defined in the transactionsDao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE is_income = 1")
fun getEarnings(): Flow<List<DatabaseTransaction>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created this extension for the same purpose:

```
inline fun <T, R> Flow<Iterable<T>>.mapIterable(crossinline transform: (T) -> R): Flow<List<R>> =
    map { it.map(transform) }
```

Usage:

```
fun getEarnings(): Flow<List<Transaction>> {
    return transactionDao
        .getEarnings()
        .mapIterable { transaction ->
            transaction.asDomainModel()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Small add on to philip's answer, In your particular case you can replace the lambda with a [callable reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type) to make the code more concise. this can be done as

```
.mapIterable(Transaction::asDomainModel)
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice, my code looks alot cleaner now !